# List wordpress sub-pages as drop-down list in navigation

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am currently coding a HTML website into wordpress. The problem that i'm having at the moment is that I can't seem to include a drop-down in the navigation list, via the `wp_list_pages` tag.

So that means at the moment, the "products" list-item, on hover, does not drop down to reveal pages (or sub-pages in this case). This is due to the fact that I could not include the `<ul>` tag with the sub-pages as child list-items within the `<?php wp_list_pages ?>`.

At the moment, the code i'm using to generate the pages on the wordpress site is 
 `<?php wp_list_pages('include=18,3,9,11,13,15,7&depth=2&title_li='); ?>`

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem and include navigation drop-downs in my wordpress site.

For illustration purposes, i've uploaded the HTML page in question into my mobileme page for you guys to have a look. I'm trying to achieve the same effect in wordpress when i hover over the "products" button in the navigation. If you have a look at my source file using firebug, you can see that its simply a case of giving "products" its `<ul>` and including the sub-pages as list-items within it.

The HTML page is on [web.me.com/zubby](http://web.me.com/zubby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by downloading some css drop-down plugin. Even though I'm sure there's a much easier way to do this, I am happy with my result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the inner `<ul>` as `ul.menu`, try doing it as a child: `ul#navlist ul`.

Comment: cheers Kerrick. I editted the CSS. When I eventually find a way to insert the <ul> tags into the products list-item it should look the part. Any suggestions how I could do this?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you should be able to go even further with the children, specifying `ul#navlist ul li`.